# How to set Id or Name to each Form Control of a Form Array in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular

I am having set of checkbox to display I am using Form Array to group all check boxes. I wanted to know if there is any way to set a name or id to each form control so that they can be differentiated from each other.I have added the code below which I am using

The below is my code.
Template

```
<section
    *ngFor="
        let taskFields of taskFieldsArray.controls;
        let i = index
    "
>
    <mat-checkbox
        (change)="
            selectTaskField(
                allColumns[i],
                $event
            )
        "
        [formControl]="taskFields"
        [name]="
            allColumns[i].headerName
        "
    >
        {{
            allColumns[i].headerName
        }}</mat-checkbox
    >
</section>
```

Ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

declare var require: any;
const allTaskFields = require('../../../../assets/AllTaskFields.json');

@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-config-rules',
    templateUrl: './add-edit-config-rules.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-edit-config-rules.component.scss'],
})
export class AddEditConfigRulesComponent implements OnInit {
    businessConfigForm: FormGroup;
    allColumns: any[] = [];
    selectedColumns: any[] = [];

    get taskFieldsArray() {
        return <FormArray>this.businessConfigForm.get('taskFieldsArray');
    }
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) {
    this.allColumns = allTaskFields;
    }

    addRuleFormBuild(): void {
        this.businessConfigForm = this.fb.group({
            taskFieldsArray: this.buildTaskFields(),
        });
    }


    buildTaskFields() {
        const arr = this.allColumns.map((element) => {
            return this.fb.control(false);
        });
        return this.fb.array(arr);
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your code as well

Comment: @YogendraR i have added the code could you please check

Comment: the only way you can differentiate the form control is index of form array.

Comment: i can see there is a name attribute. is it not working ?

Comment: @YogendraR  the name attribute is working but it is not helping my cause actually I have to handle a button click based on which i have to check and uncheck the particular form control

Comment: so on the external button click you will check/uncheck your checkbox ?

Comment: @YogendraR yes this is what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

U will have to add one `checked` (u name it as u want) key in your `array`

```
<ng-container formArrayName="taskFieldsArray">
<section *ngFor="let taskFields of taskFieldsArray.controls;let i = index">
 <mat-checkbox 
     (change)="selectTaskField(allColumns[i],$event)"
     [formControl]="taskFields"
     [name]="allColumns[i].headerName"
     [checked]="taskFields.checked">
     {{allColumns[i].headerName}}
 </mat-checkbox>
</section>
</ng-container>
```

Your function call be something like:

```
checUncheck(){
  this.taskFieldsArray.controls.forEach((element, index) => {
     if(--some condition--){
       element.checked = true/false;
    }
  });
}
```

PS: I have never tried this myself but it should help

Comment: sorry for the downvote, I can not see in the same input tag `[(ngModel)]` and `[formControl]`

Comment: @Eliseo could you please give me some suggestion how to acheive it

Comment: @Eliseo yeah i missed it, Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The value of the elements of your array is

```
this.taskFieldsArray.at(index).value
```

-index the index of the array -start by 0-

If you want to give a `name attribute` you can use `[name]="check-"+i`

If you want relation the "allColumns" with the value you can, e.g.

```
//this give you an array with the "columns" selected
const columnsSelected=this.allColumns.filter((_,index)=>this.taskFieldsArray.at(index).value)

//this give you an array with the "headerName" of the columns
const columnsHeaderSelected=this.allColumns.map(x=>x.headerName)
                                .filter((_,index)=>this.taskFieldsArray.at(index).value)
```

NOTE: Really I don't pretty sure what do you want acheive

NOTE2: be carefully, in a mat-select the $event that you received from `change` is not true/false else a [MatCheckboxChange](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api#MatCheckboxChange) -has a property checked and a property soucer-, so, when you write

```
   <mat-checkbox (change)="selectTaskField(allColumns[i],$event) ...>
```

your selectTaskField

```
selectTaskField(allColumns[i],$event){
     console.log(event.checked) //give your if is checed or not
}
```

Comment: could you please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-with-edit-funcion1-pgdd5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadd-config%2Fadd-config.component.html and click on edit from the ag-grid row one mat dialog will open up with all fields and selected fields if will click on remove button from selected fields it respective checkbox from all fields columns should be uncheck.

Comment: if the*ngFor of the buttons is like `*ngFor="let field of selectedColumns;let i=index"` -see the `let i=index' , your button can be simply `(click)="taskFieldsArray.at(i).setValue(false)"`. Se how we can "reach" the formControl of the array using `taskFieldsArray.at(i)`

Comment: I tried this but it is not unchecking the proper one could you please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-with-edit-funcion1-vhkrjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadd-config%2Fadd-config.component.ts

Comment: Thank for your help I have resolved this issue